# Slack - How to verify interactivity requests

Tags: slack, slack-commands

Setting up my first Slack slash command. I built it out originally using the deprecated [verification token](https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api#url_verification) but, for posterity, have decided to use [signed secrets](https://api.slack.com/authentication/verifying-requests-from-slack) authentication.

Reading through the [signed secrets](https://api.slack.com/authentication/verifying-requests-from-slack) documentation, I've had no issue validating requests that come in from the initial slash command. However, interaction requests have a completely different body structure and the method for calculating a secret hash do not produce a valid result (because the request body is different).

Here is a snippet from the docs on validating signed secrets.

```
slack_signing_secret = 'MY_SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET' // Set this as an environment variable
>>> 8f742231b10e8888abcd99yyyzzz85a5
request_body = request.body()
>>> token=xyzz0WbapA4vBCDEFasx0q6G&team_id=T1DC2JH3J&team_domain=testteamnow&channel_id=G8PSS9T3V&channel_name=foobar&user_id=U2CERLKJA&user_name=roadrunner&command=%2Fwebhook-collect&text=&response_url=https%3A%2F%2Fhooks.slack.com%2Fcommands%2FT1DC2JH3J%2F397700885554%2F96rGlfmibIGlgcZRskXaIFfN&trigger_id=398738663015.47445629121.803a0bc887a14d10d2c447fce8b6703c
```

On invocation of the slash command this works as intended - the request body matches the structure in the example above. When the user interacts with the message, the response body uses the [blocks api](https://api.slack.com/messaging/attachments-to-blocks#new_payloads) - which is completely different

If I'm not supposed to use the verification token and the request body from the interactive blocks api does not allow me to compute a valid hash, how am I supposed to validate interaction requests? I must be missing something while combing through the docs.